# Obtained a multiple entry US visa; Is a Canadian visa needed to visit?

Tags: visas, canada, indian-citizens, multiple-entry

My parents have a multiple entry US visa. They want to visit relatives in Canada. Do they need to obtain a Canadian visa? They are Indian citizens/passport holders.

Answer (score 9):

Yes.  American permanent residents ("green card holders") are exempt from the visa requirement in Canada, but a US visa does not have the same effect.

Source: http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?q=1020&t=16

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Except for visitors who may enter Canada with proof of citizenship, an eTA or a temporary resident visa depending on their nationality, all other temporary residents must hold valid permits while in Canada, which must be applied before arrival, on arrival or after arrival.